# Issues implementing chosen select dropdowns within underscore.js template script

Tags: jquery, css, select, underscore.js, jquery-chosen

In my code, if I remove the 
    `<script type="text/html" class="template"> </script>`
tags from around a div section that includes some `<select>` tags, then the chosen.jquery.js stylings take effect.

If I leave the `<script>` tags, then instead of modifying the select dropdown properly, it modifies it to some kind of action link.

Heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WvUK/17/).

If you remove the  tags and the underscore and jquery calls to the template, the dropdowns will load properly.

Here's an image showing both ways:

[image]

I would like it to look similarly to the bottom option, while still using underscore's templates. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say [`_.template(some_html)`](http://underscorejs.org/#template), you get a function back, not HTML:

> **template** `_.template(templateString, [data], [settings])`
>
> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering.
>   [...]
>    f you're writing a one-off, you can pass the **data** object as the second parameter to template in order to render immediately instead of returning a **template** function.

So you're trying to add a function to your page as though it was a hunk of HTML and that doesn't work very well. Also, you were trying to put your template into the document's `<head>` area and that's not a good idea.

You need to compile the template and then run the function you get back to get your HTML:

```
var template = _.template(some_html);
var html     = template(); // Or template(data) if you have data.
```

If you do you have data for your template, you can do it one go:

```
var html = _.template(some_html, data);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3ezqV/